# QGIS 2.14 Linux/Ubuntu GRASS algorithms - This algorithm cannot be run :-(

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-processing, grass-7.0

Does someone else have the problem that GRASS Tools don't work in QGIS 2.14 Toolbox ? Error: "This algorithm cannot be run :-("
GRASS7 is enabled in Toolbox options and installed (with QGIS-GRASS Plugin etc) - tested both repos (QGIS and Ubuntugis).

Comment: Seems to bei just Ubuntu 14.04 LTS related - in Kubuntu 15.10 QGIS-GRASS from the QGIS-Main repo works fine.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.